# C++ OpenMp using one thread for whole code

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I was working on a small project (my first) using OpenMp and C++ 
The code is to calculate the correlation coefficient of two data sets (i'm learning data mining and liked to do what i learn using code)

I first wrote the code like i would normally do
Then tried to make it parallel but it got slower and i don't  think  that it's using more than one thread
This is my first time trying parallel
so i don't know if i missed something
I'am using visual studio community 2015

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cmath>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

void main() {

    vector <long double> dataSetOne, dataSetTwo, dataSetMultiplication, dataSetOnePow, dataSetTwoPow;
    long double dataSetOneSum = 0, dataSetTwoSum = 0, multiplicationSum = 0, setOnePowSum = 0, setTwoPowSum = 0;
    double correlationCoefficient = 0;

    long int i;
    long int length;


    cout << "Enter length for the Data Sets: " << endl;
    cin >> length;



    #pragma omp parallel 
    {   
    #pragma omp for 
        for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
            dataSetOne.push_back(i);
        }
    #pragma omp for 
        for (i = 0; i < dataSetOne.size(); i++) {
            dataSetOneSum += dataSetOne[i];
        }

    }
    cout << "The sum of the first Data Set is: " << fixed << dataSetOneSum << endl << endl;


#pragma omp parallel
    {
    #pragma omp for private(i, dataSetTwo)
        for (i = length + 1; i <= length * 2; i++) {
            dataSetTwo.push_back(i);
        }
    #pragma omp for private(i, dataSetTwo)
        for (i = 0; i < dataSetTwo.size(); i++) {
            dataSetTwoSum += dataSetTwo[i];
        }


    }
    cout << "The sum of the second Data Set: " << dataSetTwoSum << endl << endl;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,dataSetMultiplication,multiplicationSum)
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dataSetMultiplication.push_back(dataSetOne[i] * dataSetTwo[i]);
        multiplicationSum += dataSetMultiplication[i];
    }

    cout << "Multiplication sum of the two Data Sets: " << multiplicationSum << endl << endl;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,dataSetOnePow,setOnePowSum)
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dataSetOnePow.push_back(pow(dataSetOne[i], 2));
        setOnePowSum += dataSetOnePow[i];
    }

    cout << "Sum of the first Data Set elements raised to the power of 2: " << setOnePowSum << endl << endl;
#pragma omp parallel for private(i,dataSetTwoPow,setTwoPowSum)
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        dataSetTwoPow.push_back(pow(dataSetTwo[i], 2));
        setTwoPowSum += dataSetTwoPow[i];
    }

    cout << "Sum of the second Data Set elements raised to the power of 2: " << setTwoPowSum << endl << endl;
#pragma omp parallel
    {
        correlationCoefficient = ((length * multiplicationSum) - (dataSetOneSum * dataSetTwoSum)) / (sqrt((length * setOnePowSum - pow(dataSetOneSum, 2))) * (length * setTwoPowSum) - (pow(dataSetTwoSum, 2)));
    }

    cout << "Correlation Coefficient: " << correlationCoefficient << endl;


    if (correlationCoefficient > 0) {
        cout << "the Correlation between Data Sets is: " << correlationCoefficient << " the relation between Data Sets is positively Correlated" << endl;
    }
    else if (correlationCoefficient == 0) {
        cout << " the Correlation between Data Sets is: " << correlationCoefficient << " the relation between Data Sets is Independent" << endl;
    }
    else if (correlationCoefficient < 0) {
        cout << " the Correlation between Data Sets is: " << correlationCoefficient << " the relation between Data Sets is negatively Correlated" << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: you should try to start with a single loop, there are so many things to say here... the first one is that having multiple threads means a really huge data set else, the overhead of spawning thread would kill the expected gain. The other obvious point is that you have data contention everywhere, (and also races) for example the first loop access to datasetone with all threads without correct protection nor work split

Comment: @OznOg does using "#pragma omp for private (variable names)" help or no? And thanks in advance

Comment: Do NOT use a pushback in your parallel code. It is not thread safe. The state for the pushback (where to write data, vector length, etc) is global and you may have races between threads during the pushback().  Your code is presently incorrect and must be changed. Concerning the slowdown, if  the size of the tables is not large enough, there will be a slowdown due to thread creation, synchronisation, etc.

Comment: @AlainMerigot so if i changed the vector to an array would that help?

Comment: Definitely, yes. You should only use thread safe operations. Concerning the performances, the problem is that you do **very** simple operations in your for loops and have **many** threads synchronization  (at every `# pragma omp for`). This may dominate the processing time.

Comment: Declare your variables as close to the place they are used as possible.  In particular, use `for (long int i = 0;` so that each thread has its own version of `i`.  (This isn't the only problem with the code.)